# Org Mode Structure Templates with emacs-lisp

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I can insert a src structure template with

```
C-c C-, s
```

, but do I have to write the language every time?

Is there some expansion or completion mode that can show the available languages?;)

Comment: It depends on what you've loaded but try `C-h v org-babel-load-languages`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add entries to `org-structure-template-alist`, e.g.

```elisp
#+begin_src elisp
  (add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist
               '("sl" . "src elisp"))
  (add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist
               '("sp" . "src python"))
  (add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist
               '("sh" . "src shell"))

#+end_src
```

Then when you say `C-c C-, s`, you'll get a submenu with the options above:

```
s[h]     src shell
s[p]     src python
s[l]     src elisp
s[    ]  src
```

The last one is what you get if you press `SP` or `TAB` after the `s`.